# How could a local user on a host use a buffer overflow attack to get root access to the host?

Tags: c, security, stack, buffer, buffer-overflow

I understand in general terms how a buffer overflow attack works, but how can someone use this technique specifically to gain root access to a host? A simple example and explanation would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it's about exploiting a vulnerability in a process that runs as root: Either a server that accepts connections (sockets, pipes, etc.) or an executable with the SETUID flag.

If by "gain root access" you mean take control of a shell running as root, the buffer overflow payload must start a shell and use `dup2` to redirect its input and output to something the attacker controls (such as a socket connection to a "command and control" server running on the attacker's machine).

Comment: Oh by the way, such payload is often called a "shellcode" since its purpose is giving the attacker a shell.